# Espacio entre div

Tags: html, css

Hola lo que sucede es que quiero poner un `div` debajo del otro pero como pueden ver en el código de abajo se pone sobre el de arriba. ¿Qué me recomiendan para que se ponga inmediatamente abajo sin dejar espacio alguno?

```css
#inicio
{
    background-color:#020213;
    color:white;
    min-width :100%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:auto;
    left:0; right:0; top:0;
}

ul {
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="hola.css"/>
        <title> Cine </title>
    </head >
    <body>
        <div id="inicio">
            <h1>
            <p>hola</p>
        </div>
        <div id="hola">
        <ul>
        <
        <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Primero que nada tienes que ver que toda etiqueta que abras la cierres, si no por eso te quedan desfasados, también hay varios editores que te permiten reorganizar tu código, por ejemplo en VS la combinación de teclas Ctrl+K+D hace esta funcion, en sublime text puedes instalar Alignment y usar Ctrl+Alt+A

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar precisamente que se afecten todos los elementos `<p>` y `<ul>`, yo agregaría una pequeña modificación al CSS de ejemplo en la corrección de: [Error404](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16108/error404)

```css
/* SOLO AFECTA A LOS DESCENDIENTES DE div#inicio*/
#inicio p{
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 35px;
}

/* SOLO AFECTA A LOS DESCENDIENTES DE div#hola*/
#hola ul {
   background-color:red;
   top:0; left:0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, tienes que observar que dejas etiquetas abiertas y otras que no las cierras (`h1`, un `>` que no pertenece a nadie...).

Posteriormente, tienes que tener en cuenta que los párrafos (elemento `p`), todos los `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, etc y las listas (elemento `ul`) tienen un margen por defecto. Para quitar dicho margen tendrías que usar la propiedad `margin: 0`.

Si quieres hacer más grande la letra del primer párrafo, lo que puedes hacer, en vez de usar la etiqueta `h1` (la cual lleva un margen), puedes quitarle el margen a la etiqueta `p` y cambiar su tamaño de fuente con la propiedad `font-size`.

También puedes observar que no necesitas posicionar ningún elemento con la propiedad `position`.

**Atención:** Si haces referencia al elemento `p` harás referencia a cada uno de los elementos `p` que haya en la página. Si quisieras modificar uno solamente entonces deberías de usar un `ID` o si quisieras aplicar este estilo solamente a unos cuantos le tendrías que aplicar una clase.

Tu ejemplo corregido:

```css
#inicio
{
  background-color:#020213;
  color:white;
  min-width :100%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:auto;
  left:0; right:0; top:0;
} 

p{
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 35px;
}

ul {
   background-color:red;
   top:0; left:0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="hola.css"/>
      <title> Cine </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="inicio">
          <p>hola</p>
      </div>
      <div id="hola">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
         </ul> 
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Si quisieras modificar uno solamente entonces deberías de usar un ID". No es necesario utilizar identificadores o clases para afectar solo a unos cuantos elementos. Bastaría con usar el selector de hijo y combinarlo con`nth-child` o `first-child`/`last-child/`last-of-type`/`first-of-type`.

Comment: @guzgarcia Sí, pero imagínate que cambia el DOM por alguna circunstancia. Puede que el elemento que se encuentre en primer lugar llegue un momento que esté en segundo lugar o en otra posición distinta. Con un ID te aseguras que siempre haga referencia a ese elemento.

Comment: En ese caso, y solo en ese caso, sería válido agregar un id o clases. Si no es el caso, se puede aplicar lo antes mecionado. No es un **deberías**, es un **podrías** porque hay varias soluciones para la misma problemática. Un saludo.

Comment: @guzgarcia Bueno, quizás no haya sido la palabra más acertada, tienes razón. Sin embargo, nunca he visto a nadie usar un nth-child para referirse solo a un sólo elemento. Lo vería bien en caso de que quisieras por ejemplo que siempre la primera fila de una tabla tenga un estilo diferente o que en un dropdown alguno de los elementos tenga que tener unos estilos determinados, sin importar el contenido. Sin embargo, veo mucho más contextual (y es el motivo por el que existen los IDs) llamar a un elemento concreto con un ID concreto.

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que tienes ambos div en posición absoluta y con las coordenadas top:0; left:0; es decir tienes ambos en donde mismo, si lo quieres continuar así, solo cámbiale las coordenadas al de abajo por ejemplo, puedes poner en el segundo elemento
top:85px; left:0;

Como observación también te recomiendo usar un editor de código como visual studio code o sublime, ya que tu código tiene errores sintácticos como que le falta cerrar etiquetas como la h1 y tiene llaves de mas, de manera correcta quedaría así:

```css
#inicio {
  background-color: #020213;
  color: white;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

ul {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 85px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="hola.css" />
  <title> Cine </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="inicio">
    <h1>
      <p>hola</p>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="hola">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```